# Addition of continuous functions and compactness

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous real or complex valued on locally compact space $ X$. If {$x \in X :|f(x)| \ge k $} and{$x \in X :|g(x)| \ge k $} are compact for every $ k > 0$, how can it be proved that{$x \in X :|f(x) + g(x)| \ge k $} is compact for all $ k > 0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $|f(x)+g(x)|\geq k$ implies either $|f(x)|\geq k/2$ or $|g(x)|\geq k/2$ (otherwise it contradicts  triangle inequality ). Then $$\{x\in X:|f(x)+g(x)|\geq k \}\subset\{x\in  X:|f(x)|\geq k/2 \}\cup \{x\in X:|g(x)|\geq k/2 \}.$$